# My flask app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk delivers "Bad Request : Request Line Too Large #### > 4094"

Tags: python, apache, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm building an app using flask where the user inputs a text, and the app creates a report around it. The flask app runs on AWS elastic beanstalk, which uses CodePipeline to connect to GitHub.

When the text is beyond a certain size, the webpage delivers:

Bad Request: Request Line Too Large #### > 4094

I've determined that this probably has something to do with the request limit for apache or wsgi with elastic beanstalk. I tried increasing the request limit through the EC2 instance, but it still isn't working.

I've also tried adding a .ebextensions file to the application. I'm not sure what to do next.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?